# GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync Method does not work properly UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to find out that is my current app version package has any update available or not...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates this is not work properly while app current version and store version same.
Anyone have any idea? How can I resolve this?

```
var context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates = await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
                
if (updates.Count > 0)
{
    var version = updates[0].Package.Id.Version;
    var storeVersion = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);

    App.SLOG(LogLevel.Standard, $"Installed Version: {AppCommonMethods.GetAppVersion()} Store version: {storeVersion} Store version fullName: {updates[0].Package.Id.FullName} Package Description: {updates[0].Package.Description}");

    if (!String.Equals(AppCommonMethods.GetAppVersion(), storeVersion))
    {
        UpdateAvailable = true;
        RaisePropertyChanged("UpdateAvailable");
    }
}
```

**updates.Count** always return grater then 0 in case of same version installed and **StoreVersion** always similar with installed version. Is there any specific way to get **ms_store version**? Why **"updates.Count"** return 1 in case of Similar version installed instead of 0 ?

Comment: `updates[0]` <-- Why are you only looking at the first result?

Comment: cause it's return 1 in case of similar version

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the latest version number of your app in the Store (already published) and what's the version number you are using in your app for test?

Comment: store version and installed version are same. installed version 1.1.92.0 and store version also 1.1.92.0.

Comment: I could reproduce this. I'll need some time to investigate this.